# Groovy Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I need to code stuff in groovy and was hoping to use my favorite IDE to do it.

Does anyone know of a plugin that allows me to create Groovy projects in Eclipse?

I tried googling it but a lot of them are out of date or not maintained.

Comment: I've never used it, so I won't put it as an answer, but have you looked at Groovy Eclipse?  https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki  It looks like it's under development currently.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Groovy Eclipse](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse) and it works somewhat fine, but I have to say that the support for Groovy in IntelliJ is much better. I'd recommend getting IntelliJ Community Edition if you want to write Groovy code.

Comment: My company's workflow involves Eclipse so that's why I'm trying to use it so we don't have more programs to download :/ currently have two versions of Eclipse installed for this though so it's not a great solution :P